# $\lim_{{n \to \infty}} \left( \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + n}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + 2n}} + \ldots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + (n-1)n}} \right)$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, indefinite-integrals

$\lim_{{n \to \infty}} \left( \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + n}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + 2n}} + \ldots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + (n-1)n}} \right)$

$S(n) = \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + n}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + 2n}} + \ldots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + (n-1)n}}$

$S(n) = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + x}} dx$

$\lim_{{n \to \infty}} S(n) = \lim_{{n \to \infty}} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + x}} dx$

Am i on right way?

Comment: Where's the effort shown here and context. -1 and Vote-To-Close

Comment: Sorry for that I edited the post now you can check it

Comment: Questions like this have been asked many times before on this site.

Comment: [Indeed](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Clim_%7B%7Bn%20%5Cto%20%5Cinfty%7D%7D%20%5Cleft(%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%7D%20%2B%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7Bn%5E2%20%2B%20n%7D%7D%20%2B%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7Bn%5E2%20%2B%202n%7D%7D%20%2B%20%5Cldots%20%2B%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7Bn%5E2%20%2B%20(n-1)n%7D%7D%20%5Cright)%24&p=1). And what you wrote makes no sense. $S(n)$ depends on $n.$ It is not equal to that integral. And that integral doesn't depend on $n,$ so taking its limit as $n\to\infty$ is absurd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the result is correct for the details,
from the defenetion of Riemann Summation
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nf \left(a+\frac{b-a}{n}k \right)=\int_a^b f(x) dx$$
denote the formula by N So,
$$ N=\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+(k-1)n}} $$
$$=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{k}{n}-\frac{1}{n}}} $$
$$=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \left(1+\frac{k}{n}\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}} $$
put a=0 , b=1 in Riemann Summation
$$N=\int_0^1\left(1+x\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}} dx=\left(2\left(1+x\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)^1_0  $$
$$ \therefore \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+(k-1)n}}=2\sqrt{2}-2 $$

Comment: Please do not post answers to such an FAQ and megaduplicate (see Adam's comment and my link above)